# What exactly happens when you clear storage for an android app

Tags: android

When my android app is first launched it runs through an initialization routine to set everything up the first time.  If I then go into settings and Clear Storage for my App, it no longer starts. Just hangs on the initial icon splash screen. I would expect it act as if it was just installed fresh.

I'm wondering **what exactly happens when you clear the storage?**

My app uses `SQLite` and `SharedPreferences`. The first thing I do is check both of those to see if they are present, my tables are present, and that there is data in them. If not, I do my first launch routine.

I'm not sure showing code would help, as I more curious what all gets deleted when you clear storage, because it seems to completely corrupt my app. Thanks

Comment: Clearing the app data means a fresh install of the app. Permissions if granted are revoked, `SharedPreferences` and database are deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear storage deletes all the data saved. 
So if you have a database or shared preferences all data are deleted. 
To be more clear, when you delete storage you are like a new user that download the app for the first time.